# How to generate a source map in the monorepo?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, source-maps, nrwl

I am new to monorepo.

The thing is they want me to upload a sourcemap to the rollbar.
But I don't know how to generate one.

When I ask for help they told me to read documents. I read the documents / watch Youtube videos for long time but i am still not clear about generating the source map.

In our monorepo we got lots of project

```
apps
 - ProjectA
 - ProjectB
 - ProjectC
 - ProjectD
```

The thing is i want to generate source map for the `ProjectC`.

To generate the source map I think i need to build the project ( tell me if i am wrong )
so I look into the project.json. But I don't see the build command.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/ProjectC",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/ProjectC/src/**/*.ts"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["coverage/apps/ProjectC"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/ProjectC/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

How can i configure so that it will produce a sourcemap file? ProjectC is a vue app.

The thing is in the `tsconfig.app.json`. I see the configuration like this. But I don't find the source map. Is this file related to generating source map?

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest"],
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```